# Dynamically retrieve tenant id from an Azure blob-triggered function app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions

I've written a blob-triggered function app that communicates with a backend REST API that requires a tenant id parameter as it supports multi-tenancy. The function app will be deployed to multiple tenants since, from my understanding, a blob trigger function app cannot listen to more than one container. If that's not the case, that would solve my problem differently. However, assuming that is not the case, I need to dynamically retrieve the tenant id that the function app is running in. I'd appreciate some guidance. TIA.

Comment: So the function is deployed in each tenant? Can't you set the tenant id as a configuration value for the deployed function?

Comment: i'd think that is the only option. i dont think tenant id is exposed anywhere

Comment: @PeterBons I currently have it as a configuration value using Azure App Config service. It requires a connection string to be set during host configuration, so every tenant deployment will require a modification to the Program.cs, not an optimal solution. I'd rather use configuration builder, but unable to get that to work as the HostBuilder method is quite different than the WebApplication.CreateBuilder method that I'm used to.